# Ticket validated but no PGT Iou transmitted

Tags: proxy, single-sign-on, cas, phpcas

I am trying to make a proxy CAS webapp using PHPCAS library version 1.3.3. At first I tried an example from the docs but unfortunately I got an error and said that I wasn't authenticated.

I was using the `example_proxy_GET.php` and on the log it said like this :

`Authentication failure: Ticket validated but no PGT Iou transmitted [AuthenticationException.php:80]
Reason: no CAS error [AuthenticationException.php:94]`

The authentication was successful on validate the ST (Service Ticket) but the log also said that :
`<proxyGrantingTicket> not found [Client.php:2541]
CAS_AuthenticationException::__construct(CAS_Client, 'Ticket validated but no PGT Iou transmitted`

So, my question is that the Single Sign-On server (CAS 2.0 I think) that was not sending a PGT Iou (so there's misconfiguration on the server) or there's something wrong on the examples file?

And if the server was misconfigured, what should I do?

Thanks

**UDPATE**

I'm using a private IP address and when I tried open the CAS server log on tomcat, here's it said

`2015-04-09 11:56:41,428 WARN [org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient] - <Socket Timeout Detected while attempting to send message to [http://10.10.100.102/sso/docs/examples/example_proxy_GET.php].>`

My guess was that I should use some public IP / domain to use the CAS properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I need setup a https server to use the proxy feature on CAS.
I found the detail on here

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS+requirements